# How to export Crystal Report to PDF using Asp.net (EF)

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, export-to-pdf

```
protected void DOPrintButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ReportDocument reportdocument = new ReportDocument();
    ParameterField paramField = new ParameterField();
    ParameterFields paramFields = new ParameterFields();
    ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
    paramField.Name = "@GatePass";
    paramDiscreteValue.Value = GPLabel.Text;
    paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
    paramFields.Add(paramField);
    CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields;
    reportdocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/DO_Report.rpt"));
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportdocument;
    CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
    reportdocument.Refresh();
    reportdocument.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "Admin1");     
    reportdocument.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat,Response,true,"Report");
    Response.End();
}
```

please help?????
this code error "Missing parameter value"
help...........?
i want to export crystal report to PDF format , but i tried many codes .

Comment: This looks like poorly copied and pasted code. What's happening? what's not working? Where does the "Missing parameter value" error occur?

Comment: I agree with reckface, very poor error description

Comment: showing error "Missing Parameter Value" at  eportdocument.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat,Response,true,"Report");

Comment: Its reportdocument not eportdocument. So, correct it.